# what is the best way to avoid duplicate when there is more than one transaction at a time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a production issue basically when more than 1 user being approved at the same time. The company code for the users are the same. It is supposed to be unique. Even when i try to use begin tran and with no lock, there is still a probability that the community code can still be duplicated. Because the select statement will give the same amount and hold before updating the table. Is there any possible way i can counter this. Here is the script. Thank you.

```
   declare @currentcompanycode as nvarchar(128)

    begin tran
    set @currentcompanycode = (select max(companycode) from tb_company with (nolock))

    update tb_company set companycode = @currentcompanycode + 1 where companyid = @companyid
    commit tran
```

Comment: Stop trying to re-create the wheel, use an auto-incrementing (identity) field instead for your company codes, and let the database handle it properly.

Comment: why are you using nvarchar for `@currentcompanycode` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hold on to a lock on the tb_company table when you first select it's MAX(companycode), until you've performed the UPDATE based on the value you selected:

```
set @currentcompanycode = 
(select max(companycode) from tb_company with (HOLDLOCK, TABLOCKX))
```

Comment: hai steve, thank you for your solution. it solves almost my problem. i just need to find out is there any recommendation lets say if the table cannot be lock. as many other user will be using that table. thank you for you reply

Comment: @MRu, it is inherent in how you have approached the problem that the table *must* be locked against modification between the select and the insert - so some sort of locking is essential.  If you need purely sequential numbers (so that an Identity column cannot be used), or need to handle duplicates, you could try storing the unique sequence in another table, and locking that table instead.

Answer (score 1):

Make company code an auto increment column and let the database do the work.

Answer (score 0):

use the OUTPUT clause

```
declare @newcompanycode table
(   
    companycode int
)

update  tb_company
set companycode = companycode + 1
output  inserted.companycode
into    @newcompanycode
where   . . . 

select * from @newcompanycode
```